# InconsistentMigrationHistory - Migration .. is applied before its dependency

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have 2 models which are interdependent one of another:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True,related_name='%(app_label)s_%  (class)s_created_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated_by = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='%(app_label)s_%(class)s_updated_by', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, MetaData, PermissionsMixin):
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, blank=True, null=True, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I have issues:

```
InconsistentMigrationHistory: Migration admin.0001_initial is applied before its dependency users.0001_initial on database 'default'.
```

I tried to remove from the User the account foreign key, migrate User, then migrate accounts, account FK fails, same error.

I tried to do it starting from the Account it fails, removing FK to users.

I'm interested in doing it on a new database(server) and reset on an old database local.

On the old database, I removed my models  from `django_migrations`, and commented the dependencies between Models and associated foreign key. Tried a fake migration, still sees a dependency and I don't understand from where.

Comment: did you create a new db?

Comment: I have 2 db; one local is old (and I want to reset migrations -many operations), and a new one where I want to transfer data on the staging

Comment: the issue has occured in the local one?

Comment: in case, generating a new db will not affect your project, when you delete the db, make sure you delete all the migrations files of each app

Comment: Can you try to run the `users.0001_initial` migration first, and then run all migrations?

Comment: I did, I think I know what is the issue, I have a custom user model, and the issue is with admin and account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue, it was not directly related to Account, but Django Admin migrations, because I used a custom user, in `django_migrations`, the user migrated after admin, and I had to switch the lines.

Comment: which lines are you referencing to?

Comment: What's the real solution without loosing data?